# nUnit testing a controller extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nunit, extension-methods

UX controls framework I'm using requires an extension method on MVC controllers. A null object reference is thrown when nUnit tries to call that method (used in order to package a partial view into Json).

The author of the framework suggested calling that method through an interface, however that just postpones the null error.

Is there a way to test the ActionResult from a controller that uses an extension method?

The Controller Create() method returns the resulting partial from the extension method:

```
return Json(new { Content = viewRender.RenderPartialView(this, "ListItems/SimpleSyllabi", new[] { nS }) });
```

The extension method signature is

```
 public static string RenderPartialView(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model = null, bool removeWhiteSpace = true);
```

Error is a simple:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Result StackTrace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass2.<FindPartialView>b__0(IViewEngine e)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
   at Omu.AwesomeMvc.ControllerExtensions.RenderView(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model, String master, Boolean partial, Boolean removeWhiteSpace)
   at Omu.AwesomeMvc.ControllerExtensions.RenderPartialView(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model, Boolean removeWhiteSpace)
   at Flipprs.nUnitHelpers.Awesome.ViewRender.RenderPartialView(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model, Boolean removeWhiteSpace) in A:\Stephan\Source\Workspaces\AchievementCards\Develop-Payment(v0.0.11.0)\Flipprs.Web\Helpers\Awesome\nUnitHelpers.cs:line 17
   at Flipprs.Controllers.SyllabusAjaxListController.Create(SyllabusCreateViewModel scvm) in A:\Stephan\Source\Workspaces\AchievementCards\Develop-Payment(v0.0.11.0)\Flipprs.Web\Controllers\SyllabusAjaxListController.cs:line 217
   at Flipprs.Tests.Controllers.SyllabusAjaxListControllerTest.SyllabusAjaxListController_CreatePUT_ReturnsJson(String HTTPreqAUEmail) in A:\Stephan\Source\Workspaces\AchievementCards\Develop-Payment(v0.0.11.0)\Flipprs.Tests\Controllers\SyllabusAjaxListControllerTest.cs:line 484
Result Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The Integration Test 'Setup':

```
 private IViewRender viewRender;

viewRender = new ViewRender();



controller = new SyllabusAjaxListController(viewRender, photoPlaceholderService, activityService, syllabusService,
            userService, organisationService, userManager);
```

Then in the test (excerpts)

```
  [Test, Sequential]
            public void SyllabusAjaxListController_CreatePUT_ReturnsJson()
{
    ActionResult result_ar = controller.Create(validModel);

            JsonResult result = result_ar as JsonResult;
}
```

Integration Test Mocks

```
        Mock<ControllerContext> controllerContext;
        Mock<HttpContext> httpContext;
        Mock<HttpContextBase> contextBase;
        Mock<HttpRequestBase> httpRequest;
        Mock<HttpResponseBase> httpResponse;

        Mock<IIdentity> identity;
        Mock<IPrincipal> principal;
        Mock<GenericPrincipal> genericPrincipal;
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in code to give us a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Is there a specific part that is unclear?  There is a huge amount of code involved, my guess is that someone who has tested controllers knows what I'm talking about and may know a solution.

Comment: I have a lot of experience testing controllers, which is why I asked you so show a sample of the code. You have not given much to go on. What is the extension? what is it accessing that it results in a null error. Most likely a context or implementation concern is missing that would have been there at run time that is not there when unit testing in isolation. So you see there are a lot of reason that your code fails, but I can't help if I do not know what is going on.

Comment: @Nkosi I've added the extension method signature, none of the parameters are null.  To clarify, during the 'normal' MVC pipeline, the code executes; but during integration testing I get an error.  My guess is that the way the controller is passed to the extension method doesn't work (sufficiently) when managed by nUnit during testing.   Thanks for offering to help.

Comment: Can you include the full exception and stack trace? And the test itself

Comment: Error and stack trace are posted, the test is two-hundred lines and there are helper methods.  Let me know where to start!

Comment: Ok let me review the stack trace first and we'll go from there

Comment: I've also provided how the extension method is called in the controller.  I've copied the call over to the test and get the same result.  It seems the null ref comes from lack of 'access' to the partial?

Comment: Took some google foo to find this https://www.aspnetawesome.com/forum/question/1629/nunit-error-ajax-list-create and the provided answer is valid. what was the problem with implementing what was suggested there.

Comment: Mock the renderer abstraction to return a string when invoked so that the method under test can flow to completion and you can assert you expected behavior.

Comment: That link is my question to the author mentioned ... how do I ' mock the renderer to return a string'?  A code snippet maybe as the answer?

Comment: Which is why I asked to see the Test so I would know what you did and what should be mocked.

Comment: Some test code above, I had moved away from the mock, but will add it back, but still really don't know exactly how to get the string from the extension method renderer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the subject under test may be tightly coupled to 3rd party implementation concerns that make testing it in isolation difficult.

I suggest mocking the view render abstraction referred to in your original statement

```
public interface IViewRender {
    string RenderPartialView(Controller controller, string viewName, object model = null, bool removeWhiteSpace = true);
}
```

to return a string when invoked so that the method under test can flow to completion and you can assert you expected behavior.

```
//Arrange

//...

var viewRenderMock = new Mock<IViewRender>(); //Using Moq mocking framework
viewRenderMock
    .Setup(_ => _.RenderPartialView(It.IsAny<Controller>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), true))
    .Returns("some fake view string");

//...

var controller = new SyllabusAjaxListController(viewRenderMock.Object,...) {
    //...
};

//Act
var result = controller.Create(validModel) as JsonResult;

//Assert
result.Should().NotBeNull(); //FluentAssertions

//...other assertions.
```

Comment: Two questions: what is the limitation for the nUnit instantiated controller that the extension method is null? Just to confirm, there is no way (while using the extension method) to get the Json result via an integration test?

Comment: the controller is limited by if it tries to access dependencies that are only available at run time that cannot be properly provided when testing. An actual integration test would mean that you are using the actual MVC pipeline which would include all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: I've updated the question with the pipeline Interfaces that I've mocked so far. .. what else would be required for a 'full' integration test with access to all dependencies  ?