# Integration Test: Microsoft.Owin.Selfhost vs Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost (or Selenium)?

Tags: .net, nunit, integration-testing

I have [controller extension methods that are tightly coupled to the controller being tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886517/nunit-testing-a-controller-extension-method) and would like more complete information about the controller's behavior  than Mocking a method response will give.

Is the best option self-host?  I see nuget packages for  Microsoft.Owin.Selfhost and Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost, which would be preferred for a MVC5 (ie non-core) web application using Owin.Security and Identity.Owin?

Could Selenium be any help?  I'd rather test an HTML/Json response than use coded UI tests.